# what is the default millisecond value in XmlGregorianCalender?

Tags: java

I am reading value from the XML by unmarshalling,

Here is the format **04:09:20.90**, return type of this is XMLGregorianCalender.

if i call XmlGregorianCalender.getMiliseccond() its returning 90,

but if there is no miliseconnd ***ex***: **04:09:20** then
 what should be the value if i call XmlGregorianCalender.getMiliseccond()??

As per my understanding it should return **0** but here in my application its returning **52**,

Ideas?

Comment: How did you create `XMLGregorialCalendar`? You should post an example of the code causing the issue.

Comment: It should return 0 in case you didn't initialize it with a timestamp.

Comment: Depends on which subclass you instantiate, surely - a subclass could call the set time method in its constructor.

Comment: And do you mean `XMLGregorianCalender` or `XMLGregorianCalendar`?

Comment: calendAr should return FIELD_UNDEFINED (aka Integer.MIN_VALUE). source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#getFractionalSecond%28%29

Comment: byte[] convertTimeToArray(XMLGregorianCalender time){ byte[] b=new byte[1]; b[0]=time.getMilisecond(); return b;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read into [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#getMillisecond()):

> The returned value is the rounded down to milliseconds value of
>   getFractionalSecond(). When getFractionalSecond() returns null, this
>   method must return DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED.

And `getFractionalSecond()` return `null` when the optional field is not defined.

Comment: thanks teo,  you meant to say it should return 0x80000000 when its not initialized

Comment: if its in that case where exactly 0x32 value is coming, could u please explian??

Comment: I don't understand what you say... FIELD_UNDEFINED is -2147483648 if you read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED

Comment: yes you are write Teo, it will write -2147483648(0xF3333334) and i was writing in byte hence i was getting 34.. Thanq